# Correlation vs Causation

Tags: statistics, correlation, causality

1. We know that Correlation does not imply causation and in the same way, we also know that causation does not imply a linear correlation, however, for the sake of simplicy let's assume that our model is a simple linear regression model, then can I assume that my model implies causation if the correlation coefficient is equal 1?
2. In an excerpt I was reading they give an example of causation as below:

"Example of causality:
First, you need to check if there is a correlation between the two variables, this is done with correlation analysis. If there is a significant correlation, the second condition must still be tested.
The second condition can be confirmed either by theory or if there is a time sequence. In this case, there is a clear time sequence. If there is a correlation, it is clear that the variable "age at which the first sentence is spoken" influences the variable "later school success", the other way around is not possible."

Isn't the above example only an example of correlation? Since age only influences school success and doesn't cause it.  A more formal way to paraphrase my question, in causality we know that Action A is always followed by Event B, and in the above example, this is not stated anywhere, so why is it an example of causation?

Comment: It's not.  Causation can not be deduced in this manner.  If nothing else, there could always be some "hidden" factor that produces both observables.

Comment: for which part of the question 1 or 2 ?

Comment: The second.   As a general rule:  you can never deduce causation without a model.  The data alone can't imply it.

Comment: I don't understand the first.  If your model is a linear function, then what does "causation" mean?  The mere fact that the data is linear doesn't tell you anything about causation.

Comment: A might cause B and C with correlation 1 but B need not cause C even with correlation 1.

Comment: Is there a rigorous definition for "causation"?

Comment: Rigorous definition for causation: A caused B if, had A not occurred, B would not have occurred. This is the rigorous definition at the counterfactual level. At the intervention level, $A$ causes $B$ if $P(B|\operatorname{do}(A))>P(B).$